# Trying to understand ThreadPool.map with enumerate

Tags: python, multithreading

I don't understand the purpose of (*p) in this code.

Can anyone please help?
I am new to this.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool=ThreadPool()
def mul(x,y):
    print  x*y

out=[4,5,6]
pool.map(lambda p: (lambda i, prediction:
            mul(prediction, i))(*p),
            enumerate(out))
```

Comment: I could also head over to the documentation on ThreadPool.map

Comment: no what i dont understand is the flow of this code

Comment: how labmda inside a lambda is working out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the first lambda, it returns a tuple of two values. Thus in the second lambda, `p` consist in the returned tuple.

To get each of the two variables out of this you have to unpack them which is exactly what the asterisk does.

It does this:

```
i, prediction = p
```

This is required here as `multiprocessing.pool.map` only takes one argument for the function call.

Comment: @Omerjaved glad it helped. Consider accepting the answer to close the topic :) Welcome again and consider reading all ressources: [tour], [ask]

Answer (score 1):

If rewritten as a single threaded application, you'd get something like this

```
for i, prediction in enumerate(out):
    mul(prediction, i)
```

The `map()` function will apply a function, `p` over a collection. The "splat operator" is unpacking the enumeration over each thread

I think that inner lambda could be written, for example

```
def foo(*args):
    mul(args(0), args(1))

foo(enumerate(out))
```

Comment: Thanks Cricket007 Now i get it, Want to upvote but cant